# Angular view not updating when controller has been updated

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am running into an issue where a variable is being updated in my controller, but the update is not being reflected in the view.

The variable that is supposed to be displayed on the front end is loginErrorMessage, but the variable won't appear if I navigate away and then back to this page despite being updated in the controller.

Below is the controller:

```
function LoginCtrl($rootScope, $state, $scope, UserService, AttributesService){
    var vm = this;
    vm.loginErrorMessage = '';
    vm.email = '';
    vm.password = '';
    vm.doLogin = doLogin;
    vm.successLoginJoinApiResponse = successLoginJoinApiResponse;

    function doLogin(){
      if(UserService.validateLoginCredentials()){
        UserService.loginUser()
        .success(function(response){
          vm.successLoginJoinApiResponse(response, false);
        })
      }else{
        vm.loginErrorMessage = 'Incorrect Email or Password';
        console.log(vm.loginErrorMessage)
        //vm.loginErrorMessage is updated at this point
      }
    }

    function successLoginJoinApiResponse(response, join){
      // stuff happens here, not where the issue is.
    }
  }
```

Here is the Route:

```
.state('app.login', {
    url: '/login',
    cache: false,
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller:'LoginCtrl as app'
      }
    },
  })
```

And here is the view:

```
<ion-view view-title="" class="">
  <ion-nav-bar class="white-back">
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-content scroll="false" class="white-back has-header">

    // This is where the variable should be displayed
    <div class="login-error-message" ng-bind="app.loginErrorMessage">
    </div>

    <div class="center-everything mar-top-25">
      <form ng-submit="app.doLogin()">
        <div class="list pad-20 pad-top-30 pad-bottom-0">
          <label class="item item-input input-login">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="app.email">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input mar-top-15 input-login">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="app.password">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="pad-20 pad-top-0">
          <a class="link" ng-click="app.doLogin()">
            <button class="button button-block blue-back white" id="button-submit-stuff" type="submit"><b>LOGIN</b></button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

UserService.validateLoginCredentials() returns false and so the script goes to the else statement and somewhere in there is where it fails.

I have tried running $scope.$apply(), but I get an $apply() already in progress error.

I have also noticed that the variable will appear for just a moment when I navigate away from the page.

I am also running this through Ionic.

If anyone has any advice I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but in your doLogin function, is the `UserService.validateLoginCredentials()` method async and returning a promise? Because in that case the code in else block will never run.

Comment: No that's actually just an if/else statement in the service that doesn't return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

so you first validate login Credentials and then try to login?

I'm guessing that the UserService.loginUser is missing the part of .error().

```
function doLogin(){
  if(UserService.validateLoginCredentials()){
    UserService.loginUser()
    .success(function(response){
      vm.successLoginJoinApiResponse(response, false);
    })
    .error(function(err){
        vm.loginErrorMessage = 'Incorrect Email or Password';
        console.log(vm.loginErrorMessage)
        //vm.loginErrorMessage is updated at this point
    });
  } else{
    vm.loginErrorMessage = 'Incorrect Email or Password';
    console.log(vm.loginErrorMessage)
    //vm.loginErrorMessage is updated at this point
  }
}
```

Just so you also know: the success/error shorthand is deprecated in angular 1.5
but you could rewrite this:

```
function doLogin(){
  if(UserService.validateLoginCredentials()){
      UserService.loginUser()
          .then(function(response){
              vm.successLoginJoinApiResponse(response, false);
          },
          function(err){
              vm.loginErrorMessage = 'Incorrect Email or Password';
              console.log(vm.loginErrorMessage);
              //vm.loginErrorMessage is updated at this point
          });
  } else{
      vm.loginErrorMessage = 'Incorrect Email or Password';
      console.log(vm.loginErrorMessage);
      //vm.loginErrorMessage is updated at this point
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hey, UserService.validateLoginCredentials() is actually returning false, and so the script goes to the else statement and thats where it fails. I should have made that clear in the initial question